# Java Code to select two pools of resources if condition is met for two types of agents, and one pool to another type of agent

Tags: java, conditional-statements, resources, pool, anylogic

I'm trying to set the resource pool selection conditioned on the agent.

I need to assign to type 1 resource pool A, and to the remaining 2 types BOTH of the other resources. (as a side note, this is so that on these remaining 2 types of agents, any resource can be assigned and it is based on a priority param).

**I need something like this:**

```
agent.type==1? resoursePool_A : (resoursePool_B , resoursePool_C );
```

**or**

```
  agent.type==1? resoursePool_A : resoursePool_B && resoursePool_C ;
```

I tried many things, but only this code does something close:

```
agent.type==1? resoursePoolA : agent.type==2? resoursePoolB : nursesTypeMS;
```

However, this is not what I need , as this assigns Pool A to type 1, pool B to type 2 and pool C to type

Any tips onto how code it?

Comment: To clarify, is the intention to have type 2 and type 3 agents get either resourcePool B or resourcePool C at random or is there a deterministic condition?

Comment: The preference would be to seize type 2 first, then type 3. (this is done already with a resource selection / unit with top rating / where rating=type), and it works ok.

However, if it is at random it would be interesting as well to consider the differences in the simulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this functionality can be achieved using two **Seize** blocks? As the agents come in they are separated by a **SelectOutput** block into two flows: `agent.type == 1` flow going to a **Seize** block (let's call it *seize1*) that only takes resources from *resourcePoolA* and all other agents (i.e. 1, 2) are sent to a different **Seize** block (let's call it *seize2*) that picks either from *resourcePoolB* or *resourcePoolC*.

Alternatively you can use ternary expression as follows:

```java
agent.type==1? resoursePoolA : randomFrom(List.of(resoursePoolB, resourcePoolC));
```

The above will pick resourcePoolA for agents of type 1 and randomly pick from B or C for all other types.